# No module named linear_modelsklearn._model

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn

from sklearn.linear_modelsklearn._model import SGDClassifier
No module named linear_modelsklearn._model

I am on OSX version 10.9.4
Python 2.7.6
numpy 1.9.0
scipy 0.14.0
scikit-learn 0.15.2
 What I am missing? Thanks.
(import sklearn works fine but not the model)

Comment: Apparently the OP had copied his code directly from the typo in [this book](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=OOotAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=from+sklearn.linear_modelsklearn._model+import+SGDClassifier&source=bl&ots=44s8oHcRj7&sig=hHgDhEe7aovo4us4QYwji1TgrAU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=from%20sklearn.linear_modelsklearn._model%20import%20SGDClassifier&f=false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import seems wrong, try:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
```